# How i can setup a nginx cache strategy that first try amazon s3, then memcache and do a fallback on miss?

Tags: nginx, amazon-s3, memcached

i have a large site with lot of pages that almost never change, right now i am using two memcache servers (amazon elasticache), but this its really expensive.

Thats why for this files that barely never change i want to upload them to amazon s3 and shutdown 1 memcache server.

Here is my conf;

```
location ~ /longterm/(.*){
   proxy_pass http://amazonS3bucket;
   proxy_intercept_errors on;
   proxy_next_upstream http_404;
   error_page 404 503 = @fallback_memcached
}

location @fallback_memcache {
   set $memcached_key $uri;
   memcached_pass     name:11211;
   error_page         404 @fallback;
}

location @fallback {
   try_files $uri $uri/index.html
}
```

I dont know why but the config doesnt work on the final fallback;
if i got an amazon S3 hit it works,
if i got an amazon S3 miss and a memcache hit it works,
but if i got an amazon S3 miss then a memcache miss when it try to resolve the las fallback it fails.

I am also thinking in use the amazon s3 fuse http://code.google.com/p/s3fs/ instead of the proxy pass i think it would be easier for implement, i would also be less performant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a quote from [the official documentation](http://nginx.org/r/recursive_error_pages):

> #### recursive_error_pages
>
> *default:*     `recursive_error_pages off;`
>
> Enables or disables doing several redirects using the `error_page` directive.